# Showing $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sin^p x}$ is finite for $0<p<2$.

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> I am trying to prove the indefinite integral
>   $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sin^p x}$$
>   is finite for $0<p<2$.

I tried using Wolframe alpha but the expression it gives is weird. (When putting $p=2$ you don't get what you expect). Any ideas?

(For $p=2$, the integral diverges, since $\int \dfrac{1}{\sin^2 x}=-\cot x$).

Comment: According to Mathematica, $$\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{1}{\sin^{1.5}(x)}dx$$ does not converge. Not sure if it is right, though. Check the link. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1%2Fsin(x)%5E1.5,%7Bx,0,2*pi%7D%5D     Note the link is cut off due to presence of *, copy and paste it.

Comment: Complex integration gives negative to this question as we get
$$\int_{|z|=1|}\dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{2i}(z-\frac1z)\right)^p}\dfrac{dz}{iz}=2^pi^{p-1}\int_{|z|=1|}\dfrac{z^{p-1}}{(z^2-1)^p}dz$$
has an essential singularity in $z=0$ (If I don't mistake).

Comment: @Cocomos if you plug in the original integral (with `p`) to Mathematica, with  `Assumptions -> 0 < p < 2`, it tells you that it only converges for p<1, as the top answer states.

Comment: How is $\sin(x)^p$ defined for $x\in(\pi,2\pi)$ and $p\in(0,2)\setminus\mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may realize that it is enough to make sure the convergence near zero. You can use the properties of the sine function to easily extend the argumentation to the other singularities.

For $x\in(0,\pi/2)$ we have $\sin^p(x)\geq 2^{-p}x^p$. So:
\begin{align} 
\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{1}{\sin^p(x)} dx\leq 2^{p}\int^{\pi/2}_0 x^{-p}dx
\end{align} 
The integral on the right hand side is finite iff $p<1$. So your original integral convergent for $p<1$. For all other cases it is divergent use $\sin(x) \leq x$ and do similar things as above. And finally conclude.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
Write
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{\sin^{2-p}x}{\sin^2x}\,dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^{2-p}x(1+\cot^2x)\,dx$$
and use integration by parts!

Comment: Use the fact that $ \frac x {\sin x} $ is bounded. You only have to show that $x^{-p}$ is integrable.